# Windows | Active Directory script | PHP

Tags: php, windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a PHP application that makes changes to the active directory. Now i have a powershell script, look below ($username is passed through via php):

```
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $username
```

If I run that script via command prompt, boom it works fine. However if I run it through PHP (cgi), it does not work and the change is not made, also no errors in the browser.

So after alot of trial and error, i found that READING from the active directory works fine with php, such as this script:

```
Get-ADUser $username -Properties GivenName
```

However WRITTING to the active directory, such as the first script mentioned does not work.

I managed to look in the Apache logs and found this useful piece of information:

```
Disable-ADAccount : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
At C:\scripts\lock.ps1:4 char:1
+ Disable-ADAccount -Identity $username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (12PotterH:ADAccount) [Disable-ADA 
   ccount], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirec 
   tory.Management.Commands.DisableADAccount
```

How can I overcome this?

**Things to note:**
- I am running windows server 2012

- I have given full permissions to php-cgi,powershell,cmd,xampp folder
- I am using xampp (apache)
- The actual active directory is on ANOTHER local server then the one running xampp

I have also tried adding the server parameter to the script like so:

```
Disable-ADAccount -Identity $username - Server SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Does the user running the script have rights in ActiveDirectory to disable users/that user?

Comment: Anyway to find out exactly which user is running the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify credentials in the powershell cmdlets, then it is likely attempting to run the scripts as the application pool identity on the server hosting the php site.

The correct way to work around this would be to specify credentials in the powershell scripts. Most AD cmdlets have a -credential parameter you can use.

Here is an example:

```
$Username = 'domain\username'
$Password = 'Password123'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Credential $Cred
```

Edit: version using credentials provided in plaintext

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: Noah, i will not be able to ask for input in the browser, so i would have to write the user/pass my self in the script. anyway to do this? i tried $Trustuser = "domain\user" but it still asks for a prompt to enter login

Comment: Did not work. One thing to note, i tried it via CMD and it still didnt work, whereas before it worked via CMD.

Comment: Once again, i think your script is wrong as it doesnt even work via CMD anymore

Comment: It says insufficient rights, that means the account you're using doesn't have rights. There is nothing wrong with the script.

Comment: Yeah, the original question i posted stated it was problem with permissions. And you have posted an ANSWER to the question, which doesnt work.

Comment: I posted a valid answer that addresses your initial question. Now you're facing a new problem because you are using an account that does not have proper permissions to AD. If you were running that from command line while specifying a proper account it would function. The reason it does not is because you're specifying a bad account.

Comment: Clearly not as i am specifying the admin account

Answer (score 0):

To add to what someone else said, if your application is going to be running these operations, you might consider using a credential file. It wouldn't be terribly secure, but I don't know how secure storing the credentials in the application would be, either. Credential objects that have been exported to a file are really useful.

One other option would be ensuring that the service / app. pool account has the appropriate access in Active Directory. If it's going to be doing things like this, I'd highly recommend making sure that it is a different account than the rest of the app pool identities, and is probably separated from other sites, too.